# Recursive Perl detail need help

Tags: perl, file, recursion, directory

i think this is a simple problem, but i'm stuck with it for some time now! I need a fresh pair of eyes on this.

The thing is i have this code in perl:

```
#!c:/Perl/bin/perl
use CGI qw/param/;  
use URI::Escape; 

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $directory = param ('directory'); 
$directory = uri_unescape ($directory); 

my @contents;
readDir($directory);


foreach (@contents) {
  print "$_\n";
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub readDir(){
 my $dir = shift;
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
  next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
  if(-d $dir.$file)
  {
   #print $dir.$file. " ----- DIR\n";
   readDir($dir.$file);
  }
  push @contents, ($dir . $file);
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}
```

I've tried to make it recursive. I need to have all the files of all of the directories and subdirectories, with the full path, so that i can open the files in the future.

But my output only returns the files in the current directory and the files in the first directory that it finds. If i have 3 folders inside the directory it only shows the first one.

Ex. of cmd call:

```
"perl readDir.pl directory=C:/PerlTest/"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many modules that are available for recursively listing files in a directory.

My favourite is File::Find::Rule

```
    use strict ;
    use Data::Dumper ;
    use File::Find::Rule ;
    my $dir = shift ;   # get directory from command line

    my @files = File::Find::Rule->in( $dir );
    print Dumper( \@files ) ;
```

Which sends a list of files into an array ( which your program was doing).

```
$VAR1 = [
      'testdir',
      'testdir/file1.txt',
      'testdir/file2.txt',
      'testdir/subdir',
      'testdir/subdir/file3.txt'
    ];
```

There a loads of other options, like only listing files with particular names. Or you can set it up as an iterator, which is described in [How can I use File::Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795490/how-can-i-use-filefind-in-perl/380090#3800908)

[How can I use File::Find in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795490/how-can-i-use-filefind-in-perl/380090#3800908)

If you want to stick to modules that come with Perl Core, have a look at File::Find.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid wheel reinvention, use CPAN.

```
use Path::Class::Iterator;
my $it = Path::Class::Iterator->new(
        root => $dir,
        breadth_first => 0
);
until ($it->done) {
        my $f = $it->next;
        push @contents, $f;
}
```

Make sure that you don't let people set `$dir` to something that will let them look somewhere you don't want them to look.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the scope of the directory handle `DIR`. `DIR` has global scope so each recursive call to `readDir` is using the same `DIR`; so, when you `closdir(DIR)` and return to the caller, the caller does a `readdir` on a closed directory handle and everything stops. The solution is to use a local directory handle:

```
sub readDir {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
    while(my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        next if($file eq '.' || $file eq '..');
        my $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
        if(-d $path) {
            readDir($path);
        }
        push(@contents, $path);
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Also notice that you would be missing a directory separator if (a) it wasn't at the end of `$directory` or (b) on every recursive call. AFAIK, slashes will be internally converted to backslashes on Windows but you might want to use a path mangling module from CPAN anyway (I only care about Unix systems so I don't have any recommendations).

I'd also recommend that you pass a reference to `@contents` to `readDir` rather than leaving it as a global variable, fewer errors and less confusion that way. And don't use parentheses on `sub` definitions unless you know exactly what they do and what they're for. Some sanity checking and scrubbing on `$directory` would be a good idea as well.