# Perl: Glob subdirectories recursively

Tags: perl, recursion, glob

How do I recursively include subdirectories in an array using glob?

I currently have `my @files = glob $PATH . '/*';` (where `$PATH = "."`) but this does not include subdirectories.

Comment: Re. *"Unfortunately, even though $WatchSubTree is set to 1, it cannot seem to monitor subdirectories."* This may just be a typo, but whether your `@files` array includes subdirectories has nothing to do with whether `Win32::ChangeNotify` is monitoring them.

Comment: I realized afterwards that my question was _solely_ about the `@files` array and not about ChangeNotify. I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540270/recursive-perl-detail-need-help)

I just changed `@files` to be `my @files = File::Find::Rule->in($PATH);`

Answer (score 1):

If you like to stick with standard modules you can use this code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;
find( { wanted => sub { push @files, $_ }, no_chdir => 1 }, $PATH );
```