# Getting a filename using Perl

Tags: perl, filenames

There is a file named *.iso, where `*` is any string (dot, numbers, alphabets, spl characters).

*.iso is located at /dm2/www/html/isos/preFCS5.3/

I want to get this filename into $filename. I know it's very simple. How can I do this in Perl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795490/how-can-i-use-filefind-in-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [File::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~tommy/File-Util-3.27/Util.pod)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Util;

my $file_util = File::Util->new;
my $base = '/dm2/www/html/isos/preFCS5.3/';
my @isos = $file_util->list_dir(
    $base,
    '--recurse',
    '--files-only',
    '--pattern=\.iso$'
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
my($filename) = glob('/dm2/www/html/isos/preFCS5.3/*.iso');
```

For more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html