# Finding files with Perl

Tags: perl, find

### [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) **and the** `wanted` **subroutine**

This question is much simpler than the original title ("prototypes and forward declaration of subroutines"!) lets on. I'm hoping the answer, however simple, will help me understand subroutines/functions, prototypes and scoping and the `File::Find` module.

With Perl, subroutines can appear pretty much anywhere and you normally  don't need to make forward declarations (except if the sub declares a prototype, which I'm not sure how to do in a "standard" way in Perl). For what I usually do with Perl there's little difference between these different ways of running `somefunction`:

```
sub somefunction;  # Forward declares the function
&somefunction; 
somefunction();
somefunction;   # Bare word warning under `strict subs`
```

I often use [`find2perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/x2p/find2perl.PL) to generate code which I crib/hack into parts of scripts. This could well be bad style and now my dirty laundry is public, but so be it :-)  For `File::Find` the `wanted` function is a required subroutine - `find2perl` creates it and adds `sub wanted;` to the resulting script it creates. Sometimes, when I edit the script I'll remove the "`sub`" from `sub wanted` and it ends up as `&wanted;` or `wanted();`. But without the `sub wanted;` forward declaration form I get this warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in lstat at findscript.pl line 29
```

My question is: why does this happen and is it a real problem? It is "just a warning", but I want to understand it better.

- The documentation and code say `$_` is localized inside of `sub wanted {}`. Why would it be undefined if I use `wanted();` instead of `sub wanted;`?
- Is `wanted` using prototypes somewhere? Am I missing something obvious in `Find/File.pm`?
- Is it because `wanted` returns a code reference? (???)

My guess is that the forward declaration form "initializes" `wanted` in some way so that the first use doesn't have an empty default variable. I guess this would be how prototypes - even Perl prototypes, such as they exist - would work as well. I tried grepping through the Perl source code to get a sense of what `sub` is doing when a function is called using `sub function` instead of `function()`, but that may be beyond me at this point.

Any help deepening (and speeding up) my understanding of this is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's a [recent example script here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734132/2019415) that I created using `find2perl`'s output. If you remove the `sub`  from `sub wanted;` you should get the same error.

**EDIT:** As I noted in a comment below (but I'll flag it here too): for several months I've been using [`Path::Iterator::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule) instead of `File::Find`. It requires `perl >5.10`, but I never have to deploy production code at sites with odd, "never upgrade", `5.8.*` only policies so `Path::Iterator::Rule` has become one of those modules I never want to do with out.  Also useful is [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class). Cheers.

Comment: Forward declaring a function is not the same as calling a function. Declaring it doesn't execute the code inside the function. So you can't simply replace `sub wanted;` with `wanted();` and co.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/prints-all-directory-names.html

Comment: For several months now I've been using [```Path::Iterator::Rule```](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule) instead of ```File::Find```.

Comment: All examples I've seen lists find(subroutine) etc on its own line. But I put it in a function, doesn't seem to work. What's going on? (sub getFiles(){ find(&procFiles, "$startPath");) won't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of File::Find. It just doesn't work *right*. The `find` command doesn't return a list of files, so you either have to use a *non-local* array variable in your `find` to capture your list of files you've found (not good), or place your entire program in your *wanted* subroutine (even worse). Plus, the separate subroutine means that your logic is separate from your `find` command. It's just ugly.

What I do is inline my `wanted` subroutine inside my `find` command. Subroutine stays with the find. Plus, my *non-local* array variable is now just part of my `find` command and doesn't look so bad

Here's how I handle the `File::Find` -- assuming I want files that have a `.pl` suffix:

```
my @file_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;       #Must be a file
    return unless /\.pl$/;  #Must end with `.pl` suffix
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}, $directory );

# At this point, @file_list contains all of the files I found.
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
my @file_list;

find ( \&wanted, $directory );

sub wanted {
    return unless -f;
    return unless /\.pl$/;
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}

# At this point, @file_list contains all of the files I found.
```

In lining just looks nicer. And, it keep my code together. Plus, my *non-local* array variable doesn't look so freaky.

I also like taking advantage of the *shorter* syntax in this particular way. Normally, I don't like using the *inferred `$_`*, but in this case, it makes the code much easier to read. My original Wanted is the same as this:

```
sub wanted {
    my $file_name = $_;
    if ( -f $file_name and $file_name =~ /\.pl$/ ) {
        push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
    }
}
```

`File::Find` isn't that tricky to use. You just have to remember:

- When you find a file  you don't want, you use `return` to go to the next file.
- `$_` contains the file name without the directory, and you can use that for testing the file.
- The file's full name is `$File::Find::name`.
- The file's directory is `$File::Find::dir`.

And, the easiest way is to push the files you want into an array, and then use that array later in your program.

Comment: Hi David W. and @tobyink I'm accepting Davids answer since - while it didn't answer my rambling question about subroutines - it did help me learn a bit more  about `File::Find` and finding files. Cheers and thanks to you both.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the `sub` from `sub wanted;` just makes it a call to the `wanted` function, not a forward declaration.

However, the `wanted` function hasn't been designed to be called directly from your code - it's been designed to be called by File::Find. File::Find does useful stuff like populating`$_` before calling it.

There's no need to forward-declare `wanted` here, but if you want to remove the forward declaration, remove the whole `sub wanted;` line - not just the word `sub`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't say understand how forward declaration works (yet), but I can see that it is not necessary here and that it is the plain function call that is producing the Uninitialized `$_` error.

Comment: Forward declaration of subs is rarely very useful. Pretty much the only time it's useful is in the situation where you have a call to a sub with an interesting prototype, and that call needs to be compiled before the sub itself has been compiled. If you have no idea what I mean, then that's OK - just don't forward declare subs, and avoid prototypes, and you'll generally be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `File::Find`, I would recommend using the `find_wanted` function from [`File::Find::Wanted`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Wanted).

`find_wanted` takes two arguments:

- a subroutine that returns true for any filename that you would want.
- a list of the files you are searching for.

`find_wanted` returns an array containing the list of filenames that it found.

I used code like the following to find all the JPEG files in certain directories on a computer:

```
my @files = find_wanted( sub { -f && /\.jpg$/i }, @dirs );
```

---

Explanation of some of the syntax, for those that might need it:

`sub {...}` is an anonymous subroutine, where `...` is replaced with the code of the subroutine.
`-f` checks that a filename refers to a "plain file"
`&&` is boolean *and*
`/\.jpg$/i` is a regular expression that checks that a filename ends in `.jpg` (case insensitively).
`@dirs` is an array containing the directory names to be searched. A single directory could be searched as well, in which case a scalar works too (e.g. `$dir`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `open` and invoke the shell `find`?  The user can edit `$findcommand` (below) to be anything they want, or can define it in real time based on arguments and options passed to a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; 
my $findcommand='find . -type f -mtime 0';
open(FILELIST,"$findcommand |")||die("can't open $findcommand |");
my @filelist=<FILELIST>;
close FILELIST;
my $Nfilelist = scalar(@filelist);
print "Number of files is $Nfilelist \n";
```