# Reading Unix find(1) output into a hash rather than array

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, find, perl-data-structures

Learning on my own but wanted to know how to put the output of a UNIX find command into a hash instead of an array.

I know this works:

```
@file_array= qx(find / -path '/{directory_path}/*' -type f -maxdepth 3 
               -name "{extension list}" 2>/dev/null );
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
$variable = qx(find / -path '/{directory_path}/*' -type f -maxdepth 3
              -name "{extension list}" 2>/dev/null);
              $hash_file{$some_extension} = $variable;
```

I am new to perl (just started learning) but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to call `find`? `File::Find` and `File::Find::Rule` are quite effective.

Comment: `$variable = qx(...)` will put the whole of the response string into the scalar variable instead of separated into lines as it is in the case of the array. `$hash_file{$some_extension} = $variable` will just copy that string to a hash element, depending on the value of `$some_extension`. But it's unclear what you're actually trying to do. What do you want in your hash? I'm guessing you're trying to filter the list of names by extension?

Comment: Yes Borodin that is exactly what I am trying to do. Any pointers on how that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick & dirty tip

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;

my $Input      = shift @ARGV;
my @SuffixList = qw(\.txt \.doc \.xls \.csv);
my $Suffixes   = join '|', @SuffixList;
my $Sources    = {};
my $MyDepth    = 5;

find({
    wanted   => sub { my $Depth = tr!/!!; 
                     push @{ $Sources->{$1} }, $_ if ($_ =~ m{($Suffixes)\z}xms 
                     && $Depth < $MyDepth) 
                },
    no_chdir => 1,
}, $Input);

print Dumper $Sources;
```

The trick with tr is from [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node=170969).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`map()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) built-in function to create a hash with the file names as the keys and setting the values to `undef` or `1` or some other more useful value:

```
perl -E 'map { $filehash{$_} = undef } 
         qx( find ./ -type f -maxdepth 3  2>/dev/null ) ; 
         say keys %filehash ;'
```

For example you could use the file extension as the value for each hash key (grabbing the extension with `fileparse()` from [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)):

```
perl -MFile::Basename -E '
         map { chomp; $filehash{$_} = ( fileparse($_, qr/\..[^.]*$/))[2] } 
         qx( find ./ -type f -maxdepth 3 2>/dev/null ) ;
         say "$_  has $filehash{$_}  extension" for keys %filehash  ;'
```

which you could then filter with:

```
perl -MFile::Basename -E ' 
         map { chomp; $files_ext{$_} = ( fileparse($_, qr/\..[^.]*$/))[2] }
         qx( find ./ -type f -maxdepth 3 2>/dev/null ) ;
         for $k (keys %files_ext) { say $k if $files_ext{$k} eq ".pdf" } ;'
```

You could then rewrite this as a script:

```
use v5.22;
use File::Basename ;
use List::Util 'any';

my %files_ext ;
my @ext  = qw(.doc .xls) ;
my @list =  qx( find ./ -type f -maxdepth 3 2>/dev/null ) ;

map { 
   chomp; 
   $files_ext{$_} = ( fileparse($_, qr/\..[^.]*$/))[2] 
} @list ;

for my $k (keys %files_ext) {   
        say $k if (any { $_ eq $files_ext{$k} } @ext ) ;
}
```

But, rather than building a hash to filter files this way you could use one of the various **modules that will help you find files using perl without running a system command to do so**. *e.g.* [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) which comes with the core perl distribution. From [**CPAN**](https://www.metacpan.org/) one of my favorites is [`Path:::Iterator::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule). Since your question asks how to add the output of `find` to a hash my answer focuses on that approach.

Here is a script that uses `Path::Iterator::Rule` to find files and then filters the results as above.

```
use File::Basename ;
use List::Util 'any';
use Path::Iterator::Rule;

my @exts = qw(.doc .xls);    
my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new()->max_depth(3);

my @dirs = $rule->all( "." ) ;

for my $file ( @dirs ) {
  if ( any { $_ eq ( fileparse($file, qr/\..[^.]*$/))[2] } @exts ) {
    print "$file \n" ;
  }
}
```

On a large set of files it may be possible to make this faster (see the [PERFORMANCE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule#PERFORMANCE) section of the `Path::Iterator::Rule` documentation)  by replacing `->all()` method with `->all_fast()` or shifting the filtering portion (*i.e.* the calls to `any()` and `fileparse()`) into a custom rule that uses an anonymous subroutine `sub{ ...}` to directly construct the filtered list of files.

Using the "lazy" iterator methods `->iter()` or `->iter_fast()`instead of the list interface also seems to help:

```
use File::Basename;
use List::Util 'any';
use Path::Iterator::Rule;

my @exts = qw(.doc .xls);   
my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new()->max_depth(3);  

$rule->and(
  sub {
    my $ext = ( fileparse($_, qr/\..[^.]*$/))[2];
    any { $_ eq $ext } @exts;
  }
);

my $next = $rule->iter_fast(".");

while (defined(my $file = $next->())) {
  print "$file\n";
}
```

On my system using a system call to Unix `find()` is fastest of all. Fast isn't always "best" though. The perl modules can give you error handling and safety that you otherwise would not get by simply slurping the output of a system command.

**Other References**

- [Finding files with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754931/finding-files-with-perl) has some good responses to a more specific `File::Find` question and has some good links in the **Related** section.
- Your question is also more generally about data structures in perl so you probably want to read the "Perl Data Structures Cookbook" documentation available on your system as [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).